# Get last two rows from a row_number() window function in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

Hopefully, someone can help me...

I'm trying to get the last two values from a `row_number()` window function. Let's say my results contain row numbers up to 6, for example. How would it be possible to get the rows where the row number is 5 and 6?

Let me know if it can be done with another window function or in another way.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ... DESC) <= 2;
```

This approach could be further extended to get two rows per each  partition:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ... DESC) <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `top` with `order by desc` like:

```sql
select top 2 row_number() over([partition by] [order by]) as rn
from table
order by rn desc
```

Comment: Never use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` it's non deterministic.

Comment: I meant to say to use `row_number()` with `partition by` etc. but as I don't have any details on columns etc. so I just added `row_number() over()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd say @Shmiel is the formal and elegant way, just in case, would be the same as :

```
WITH CTE AS
         (SELECT product,
                 user_id,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id order by product desc)
                     as RN
          FROM Mytable)
SELECT product, user_id
FROM CTE
WHERE RN < 3;
```

You will use order by [order_condition] with "desc". And then you will use RN(row number) to select as many rows as you want